# Google location history wildly inaccurate

Tags: google-location-history

I may have set a new world record in travel according to Google location history. I've noted that on Wed, 18th March 2014 I was in Sydney at 5:28pm, then in Sale Morocco at 6:06pm, then back in Sydney at 6:08pm. At this rate, I have travelled (according to google) 11,169 miles each way in about half an hour.

Also, I note on the 20th March 2014 that I did it again, this time:

- 5:25pm Sydney
- 5:27pm Jakarta
- 5:29pm Sydney
- 5:31pm Jakarta
- 5:44pm Sydney

Now I know that Google uses GPS satellites, Wi-Fi networks and the Cell networks to locate my location, but can it get the language, country and continent wrong all at once?