# Why does my Android phone think it was in Japan?

Tags: google-location-history

According to [Google location history](http://google.com/locationhistory), I was in Tokyo in February. It could be that I had so much saké I'm forgetting something important, but as far as I know I've never been to Japan.

Other questions on inaccurate location history seem mostly related to minor inaccuracies because of phone connecting to nearby WiFi points.

But what technical issue could cause the location to be off by ~6000 miles?

[image: flying to Tokyo]

Comment: try running the GPS for few mintues so it will pinpoint your real location.

Comment: Not really a rare question: [Maps location out by 12,742km - the other side of the world](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/44365/16575) / [Google location history wildly inaccurate](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/65992/16575) / **[Google Maps Location History is showing an incorrect location](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/44608/16575)** / [Gps mistaken my location and get me to trouble](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/66872/16575) / ...

Comment: @Izzy the answer on that question concerns errors of several orders of magnitude less.  the other questions concerning international size mistakes do not have answers

Comment: wim, check all of them (best *before* asking anew, as too many duplicates make it hard to gather the facts). Easy example: Two weeks ago I lived in Japan. Now I live next door to you. I didn't change the SSID of my router, and Google didn't yet update its database. So whenever your device sees my SSID, you're in Japan – according to Google... as onik also pointed out below. We've got this question at least 10 or more times, so all the facts are probably "spread around them".

Answer (score 1):

One reason could be that that location was determined from a WiFi access point, which had been previously moved from Japan to somewhere near you.

Google registers the location of each WiFi access point Android devices are connected to (if allowed in settings) and uses these to obtain a location when GPS is slow or unavailable. Unfortunately it takes some time to update the location if the access point is moved, so this kind of error can happen.